# Launch a configured Eclipse IDE from web browser

Tags: eclipse

I have come across a demonstration whereby a company launches an Eclipse IDE onto a developer's PC from a website. The Eclipse that was downloaded to the work station on the fly was configured with the plugins and applications server configuration. I did not get a chance to ask how was it done, can anyone point me to resources how this is being done?

Answer (score 1):

You might have seen [Yoxos](http://eclipsesource.com/en/products/yoxos/), which allows to configure profiles of plugins and installation of those pre-configured profiles.